# What is the meaning of "of" in respect of this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a definition for "break-in" I encountered in Oxford Languages dictionary:

an illegal forced entry **of** a building or vehicle, typically to steal something.
*"police are investigating a break-in at a house"*

I was surprised that the preposition **"of"** was used **rather than "to"**(an illegal forced entry **to a building**)

is this the meaning of this preposition in this context?

**"of"**
b. In respect to: *slow of speech*.(source: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest 'done to' - forced entry of a building, murder of a person, theft of money -- these are all crimes.

> of preposition (DONE TO)
> done to:
> *the massacre of hundreds of innocent people*
> *the oppression of a nation*
> *the destruction of the rain forest*

[Of (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)